# Getting Error Code 5 when trying to query session in PowerShell with a Virtualized PC on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, powershell

I am running into an issue with getting a permission error when I try to run the query session /server:[server-name-here] PowerShell script on a virtualized Windows device via VMWare Fusion on a Mac:

Error 5 getting sessionnames
Error [5]:Access is denied

Logged in as the same user for Windows, I can run the query session command fine on a normal Windows device and get the user session table with the information I need

I have tried setting LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1, and made sure that AllowRemotePC is set to 1, and that the same Windows account user is in the list of users that can remote into the server that I am querying the session for

I appreciate any lead as to why the same Windows user account runs into permission issue with the virtualized Windows device on a Mac, but not on a native Windows device

Thank you!

Comment: Windows credentials will not work on MAC.  Try using OAUTH2 which will work on 
Windows, MAC, and Linux.  See https://fusionauth.io/docs/lifecycle/authenticate-users/oauth/ and https://fusionauth.io/docs/lifecycle/authenticate-users/oauth/endpoints